# friendship without direct inheritance

Tags: c++, templates, c++20

Is there a way to make class holder (owner) of some other class as variables members give exclusive access without inheriting or directly writing friendship name inside those child classes?

example:

```
class A: {
int m = 0;
};

class B: {
public:
   A test1;
   A test2;

   void do() { test1.m = 2; } // error
};
```

we can make class A as template

```
template <class Friend>
class A {
friend Friend;
int m;
}

class B {
void do() { A<B> a; a.m = 2; }; // ok
}
```

Or we can do something like specify who is friend without making A to pass template argument like (not exactly remember something like)

```
class B {
   friend A;
   A test;
   void do() { test.m = 2; } // ok
}
```

But maybe there a way of know class type of B class mean typename - Parental inside A class implicitly deduce it somehow, since A is member anyway, but not passing it directly typing it's name inside <> or somehow else do automatic deduction?

I begin thoughts conceptually from do some utility function like

```
typename <Owner>
constexpr auto make_A(Owner *) {
 return A<Owner>;
}

class B {
   auto MyA = make_A(this);
}
```

So implicitly strip Parent type from (this) then pass as argument to A and make friendly to B.

But it seems same long typing as passing B inside <> of A, also as auto cannot be in non static member etc...

Key idea is to protect member variable class let it be accessable in public area - as data and it's non public methods should be hidden from anyone, except owner may call them. and not listing long list of friends inside A manually typing each time since there can be many B's freshly created etc, and not typing long names of B inside A<> etc.

Comment: you do not need a long list of friends. YOu need one friend and anybody else accessing the private members does it via that one friend. You should place your motivation first not last. Its a lot to read during which one doesnt understand why you want to avoid `friend` just to realize at the end that `friend` is a viable solution

Comment: I though make friend delegate by your though, but It makes that if my Parent will access through that auto proxy hidden (object) accessing, then others accessing too... Or maybe I miss something. example wish keep simple A.b.do(); accessible for all, but A.b.not_do() accessible only for A from inside.

Comment: Why should any type `B` be able to access the privates of an object `A` just because it has a member of type `A`? Any code could store an object of type `A`, so that would give arbitrary amounts of such code access. If your design wants to treat having a member as being worthy of special access controls, I would suggest that your design has a problem. Even derived classes only get access to `protected` rather than `private` access.

Comment: private for demo, ofcourse protected section will be choosed. idea as said let object be universal member with methods, that has public access for read only functions, and write should be enabled for object owner only.

Answer (score 4):

`friend` is a compile-time directive, so no runtime function to make it a friend.

Using `template <class Friend>` comes with its own deal of problems: each class doing A creates a new version of Friend, meaning static members of Friend won't be shared between instances, one A won't be able to access privates of another A and so on.

If you intend for A to only appear within other classes, and not stand-alone, the best option IMO is to make the entire A public, and the property holding an instance of A within B private. That way B can access all fields of its instance of A, and nobody outside B can do so, because they can't get a handle of B's instance of A.

```
class A: {
public:
    int m = 0;
};

class B: {
private:
   A test1;
   A test2;

public:
   void do() { test1.m = 2; } // ok
};
```

Comment: I don't thinking abou make it work in runtime, but I wish to let B access A, I wish semi of what you suggest, A not standalone, B accessing full A internals, key feature is that I can read something from A through it's only allowed methods, so B can write from calling methods that protected section etc. Since there lot's of A with different read only stuff, creating for each A read only methods from B to make it visible is pain same as list all friends inside A manually typing names of B-s.